# Plugins management fails with 404 on SonarQube 6.3.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

I have migrated from SonarQube 6.2 to SonarQube 6.3.1 today.
Since then, impossible to manage the pluginsd via the web interface:
"POST /sonarqube/api/plugins/update HTTP/1.1" 401 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/updates"

"POST /sonarqube/api/plugins/uninstall HTTP/1.1" 401 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/installed"

Any ideas?

Please find below multiple logs :
**es.log** (no specific error except the warning) :
2017.05.09 18:37:03 INFO  es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting es
2017.05.09 18:37:03 INFO  es[][o.s.s.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.05.09 18:37:04 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] version[2.4.4], pid[308], build[fcbb46d/2017-01-03T11:33:16Z]
2017.05.09 18:37:04 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initializing ...
2017.05.09 18:37:04 INFO  es[][o.e.plugins] [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.05.09 18:37:04 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/vbtu13--vg-root)]], net usable_space [22.1gb], net total_space [105.9gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
2017.05.09 18:37:04 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.05.09 18:37:04 WARN  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
2017.05.09 18:37:09 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initialized
2017.05.09 18:37:09 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] starting ...
2017.05.09 18:37:09 INFO  es[][o.e.transport] [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2017.05.09 18:37:09 INFO  es[][o.e.discovery] [sonarqube] sonarqube/1jRp0dGhSPGTebMmzIKSLQ
2017.05.09 18:37:12 INFO  es[][o.e.cluster.service] [sonarqube] new_master {sonarqube}{1jRp0dGhSPGTebMmzIKSLQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube, master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2017.05.09 18:37:12 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] started
2017.05.09 18:37:12 INFO  es[][o.e.gateway] [sonarqube] recovered [7] indices into cluster_state
2017.05.09 18:37:14 INFO  es[][o.e.c.r.allocation] [sonarqube] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[components][0], [components][0]] ...]).

**sonar.log** :
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3)(impossible to post with my reputation)//wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2017.05.09 18:37:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp
2017.05.09 18:37:02 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp/sq-process5998520493205071951properties
2017.05.09 18:37:14 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.05.09 18:37:14 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp/sq-process2409091727178853918properties
2017.05.09 18:37:35 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2017.05.09 18:37:35 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.220.100.56 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.3.1/temp/sq-process6009636964843033739properties
2017.05.09 18:37:47 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
2017.05.09 18:37:47 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up

**access.log** :
...............
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:01 +0200] "GET /sonarqube/api/plugins/installed HTTP/1.1" 200 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/installed" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJT"
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:01 +0200] "GET /sonarqube/api/plugins/pending HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "http://vbtu13:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/installed" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJV"
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:01 +0200] "GET /sonarqube/api/plugins/updates HTTP/1.1" 200 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/installed" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJU"
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:08 +0200] "GET /sonarqube/api/plugins/pending HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/available" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJX"
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:08 +0200] "GET /sonarqube/api/plugins/available HTTP/1.1" 200 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/available" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJW"
10.220.105.4 - - [10/mai/2017:09:29:13 +0200] "POST /sonarqube/api/plugins/install HTTP/1.1" 401 - "xxx:9000/sonarqube/updatecenter/available" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" "AVvuErdqF8rgNMzDAAJY"

Comment: Did you manage to login as admin? Have also a look at the log files and share any errors your see.

Comment: Hello.yes, I logged as admin. I tried also as a user with admin rights. But it has not helped. I have edited my post to add the logs.. But no specific error....

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround.
I do not know why, but this version does not keep the cookies on Firefox.
The issue was present for all authenticated actions... (I tried on multiple stations).

But it has worked on Chrome... So, problem solved.